# Using a chicago style in Xaringan Theme

Tags: r, citations, xaringan

I am using the [Xaringan Theme](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan) for my RStudio Markdown presentations.

All works fine but I want to change the bibliography style from "authoryear" to the Chicago Manual of Style Author-Date [Version](https://editor.citationstyles.org/styleInfo/?styleId=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.zotero.org%2Fstyles%2Fchicago-author-date).

Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is the code so far:

````
```{r, load_refs, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE}
library(RefManageR)
BibOptions(check.entries = FALSE,
       bib.style = "authoryear",
       cite.style = "authoryear",
       style = "markdown",
       hyperlink = FALSE,
       dashed = FALSE)
lit <- ReadBib("pwaLiterature.bib", check = FALSE)
```
````